# How to render image from array in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm actually new to react. I'm actually trying to import image from an array but I'm not very sure how to to do that.

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {
    return(

        <div className='dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow db w-30'>
             <img alt='robots' src={props.src}/>
            <div>

                <h1>{props.name}</h1>
                <p>{props.email}</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

in my array file i have add src as my images

```
export const robots = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Leanne Graham',
      username: 'Bret',
      email: 'Sincere@april.biz',
      src:'./assets/one.jpeg'

    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Ervin Howell',
      username: 'Antonette',
      email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv',
      src:'./assets/two.jpeg'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Clementine Bauch',
      username: 'Samantha',
      email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net',
      src:'./assets/three.jpeg'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Patricia',
      username: 'Karianne',
      email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org',
      src:'./assets/four.jpeg'
    }
  ];

  export default robots;
```

and this is where i render the file

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import Card from './Card';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'tachyons';
import {robots} from './robots';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Card src={robots[0].src} id={robots[0].id} name={robots[0].name} email={robots[0].email}/>
        <Card id={robots[1].id} name={robots[1].name} email={robots[1].email}/>
        <Card id={robots[2].id} name={robots[2].name} email={robots[2].email}/>

    </div>

    ,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

can help me with this, how can i render the images from the array? 
i have try using `src={props.src}` method to render the images but it was unsuccessful and i doubt whether am i using the correct method to render the images from the array.

Comment: For dynamic src you must use `src={require(\`${props.src}\`)}`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import Card from './Card';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'tachyons';
import {robots} from './robots';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      robots.map((robot) => {
        <Card src={robot.src} id={robots.id} name={robots.name} email={robots.email}/>
      })

    </div>

    ,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: The is with ur image URL "'./assets/four.jpeg'" in your image tag this what I rendered
<img src='./assets/four.jpeg' . . . /> . You can rather append base URL to image src

Answer (score 0):

you can using map in js like this:

```
robots.map((item, index) => (
<Card src={item.src} id={index} name={item.name} email={item.email}/>
))
```